# Tracking the popularity of a package over time?

Tags: apt, package-management, popcon

Is there any software or website that allows the user to view a graph of how popular a particular package is? The [popcon.ubuntu.com](http://popcon.ubuntu.com/) site has raw information on how many people
(who have installed `popularity-contest`) have installed a particular package, but it would be interesting to see how a package's popularity changes over time.

I remember using a website that graphed this, but I don't know if it still exist.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://popcon2.net/

> Popcon² is a website for viewing and analyzing Ubuntu's user-submitted package statistics.

**Update**: The site is down since 2014. There is [a copy on archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20121003003238/http://popcon2.net:80/).

Comment: **This** was the site I was thinking of, thanks!

Comment: The site appears to be down.

Answer (score 4):

I've found this for Debian at http://qa.debian.org/popcon.php

For example cmatrix packages: https://qa.debian.org/popcon.php?package=cmatrix

**Edit**: Here's a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-website/+bug/482550) with [a solution](http://ubuntu-popcon.43-1.org/).

Answer (score 3):

There is also [www.lesbonscomptes.com/upopcon/](https://web.archive.org/web/20121003003238/http://popcon2.net:80/) and [ubuntu-popcon.43-1.org/](http://ubuntu-popcon.43-1.org/)

The first one has more display options and data for a longer period (disclosure: its mine...)