# How do I find out how popular an application is?

Tags: application-development, popcon

For me there are two use cases when I am interested in the popularity of a given application or an application version on Ubuntu:

- There is a choice of several similar applications. Before I install one of these I would like to know which one is the most popular.
- To continue developing I get quite some motivation impulse from knowing that people actually do use my application.

Other than the [Ubuntu Populary Contest](http://popcon.ubuntu.com/) I am not aware of any other service to tell me. Sadly Popcon Ubuntu is rather out of date lately (see [bug #1067227](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/popularity-contest/+bug/1067277) and more). Alternatives listed in answers to "[Tracking the popularity of a package over time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16094/tracking-the-popularity-of-a-package-over-time)" are even more outdated.

When an application source or a DEB package is published on Launchpad we can see the download statistics of this package in the *"Download project files"* section, but this does not cover installations through a ppa, or when people installed an application from the repositories (which will be the usual case).

Is there any other way I may have missed to find out about an application's popularity?

Comment: I think popcorn is the only thing that would actually do exactly what you are looking for, apart from the not-updating thingy :(

Comment: the application needs to phone home.  Most server users probably do not want that.

Comment: They probably won't move a finger about traditional package system but maybe [telemetry](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/linux/ubuntu-reveals-desktop-telemetry-for-the-first-time/) will work with snap ones. Anyway, [here](https://store.steampowered.com/hwsurvey?platform=linux) are some interesting popularity info of Steam users.