# Number of package releases / upgrades over time

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates

Background:
I came back to an old server of mine today and ran `apt-get update; apt-get upgrade` only to find there were no updates available.
Subsequently tried `dist-upgrade` as well.
This baffles me a bit b/c I hadn't accessed the machine in quite a while. On the other hand, it is running 14.04., so maybe not a lot of updates are released there anymore.

I am wondering if I can see online somewhere how many updates have been released since a certain date or between two dates.
Is there such a resource available?
Can I alternatively construct something like this if I have access to a virtual machine with the same release as the server?

edit1: This seems related [Tracking the popularity of a package over time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16094/tracking-the-popularity-of-a-package-over-time) but the web site "popcon" suggested there appears to be offline.

Comment: DO you have unattended-upgrades set up? What does `/var/log/apt/history.log` have to say?

Comment: That's a fair question. It's a VPS, but I don't think so. history.log reveals: 4-5 packages updated today (that came from nodejs ppa) and history.log.2.gz shows the last update from 2015-11-13 (installed golang, not even full upgrade either)
There's a folder /var/log/unattended-upgrades, but it's empty.